# How can I know when websocket send message back to my screen? (React-Native)

Tags: javascript, websocket, react-native, react-native-ios

I use websocket to send a request and wait for it to send messages back to me so I can re-render my View. But my question is how can I know when websocket send me a message (it will send me messages for more than 1 time) and how can update my state so I can re-render my view?

here is my code to initialize my state:

```
               constructor(props) {
               super(props);
               this.state={
                 result:[],
                }
```

here is my websocket code:

```
            let ws = new WebSocket('xxx');

            ws.onopen = function(evt) { 
                console.log("Connection open ..."); 
                ws.send(JSON.stringify({
                    'id': 100,
                    'g': r1,
                }));
            };

            ws.onmessage = function(evt) 
            {                  
              let msg = JSON.parse(evt.data);                  
              this.setState({
                result: msg,
              })

            };

            ws.onclose = function(evt) {
              console.log("Connection closed.");
              console.log(evt.code, evt.reason);
            };

            ws.onerror = function(evt) {
              console.log(evt.message);
            };
```

How can I let my screen to re-render after my state is been updated(because websockt send me back more messages)?

Thanks for helping!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It used to be automatically. A react components listen to props and the state and re-render itself on it.

The only way to prevent re-render on props/state change is `shouldComponentUpdate` method, if it returns `false`, the component will not get updated and will do if the method return `true`.